# Why are most air compressors petrol powered

Tags: tires, air

I am looking to buy an air compressor. However most of the ones I see online are petrol powered for example https://www.amazon.co.uk/Black-Decker-195-NK-Compressor/dp/B0789JT29J/, if I don't need it portable wouldn't one that attaches to mains electricity be just as good?

Comment: The compressor in your link is mains electricity powered - "Power Source Corded electric Voltage 230 volts"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vast majority of air compressors sold in the UK are mains powered - in fact when I was looking a year or so ago I couldn't find any affordable petrol powered ones (my garage doesn't have mains electricity) - I ended up buying battery tools instead.

Comment: Ah ok, i thought that was an engine on it, obviously that is just the part for compressing the air

Comment: Yep - most air compressors are basically a reverse IC engine - the electric motor makes the crankshaft go round, which moves the piston in and out, and pumps air through into the tank